# Hive : Cannot read file from Google Cloud Platform

Tags: java, maven, hive, google-cloud-storage, nosuchmethoderror

I am trying to read a file present in a GCP bucket in a hive query.

Basically, all i want to do is

```
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Blob;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobId;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;

Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
Blob blob = storage.get(BlobId.of(bucketName, srcFilename));
String fileContent = new String(blob.getContent());
return fileContent;
```

now, when i run this on my mac, it works (I have the gcloud setup in a way that i can access the buckets)

Now, i want to have the same functionality but in a hive udf. So, i built a very simple jar

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDF;     
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFType;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Blob;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobId;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;

@UDFType(deterministic = true)
public class MyAwesomeUDF extends GenericUDF{

@Override
    public String process(String srcFilename, String bucketName) throws IOException {
        Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    Blob blob = storage.get(BlobId.of(bucketName, srcFilename));
    String fileContent = new String(blob.getContent());
    return fileContent;
    }

}
```

and here is my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-storage -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.71.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-serde</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <plugins>
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>hive-exe-jar-with-dependencies</finalName>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>repackaged.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Next, i build this jar and i am able to run this on the VM.

Finally, here is the hive query i want to run

```
add jar /path/to/my/awesome/jar;
use myDb;

create temporary function awesome_fun as 'package.path.to.my.MyAwesomeUDF';

        select
            awesome_fun('bucketName','srcFileName');
```

but here i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.services.storage.Storage$Objects$Get.setUserProject(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/api/services/storage/Storage$Objects$Get;
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.getCall(HttpStorageRpc.java:403)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.get(HttpStorageRpc.java:411)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$5.call(StorageImpl.java:198)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$5.call(StorageImpl.java:195)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:89)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:51)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.get(StorageImpl.java:195)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.get(StorageImpl.java:209)
```

the error happens at

`Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();`

Moreover, after i build the jar i can see (using `jar -tf`) that `com.google.api.services.storage.Storage$Objects$Get` is present.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I built and ran your application and all was well ... I executed using:

mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.kolban.App


My java -version reported 1.8.0_212.  How are you executing your app?

Comment: same, i executed with mvn exec

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a missing method, make sure the class files that you are actually running are updated when you compile or verify that the compiled class and the libraries are in the same version.